# Why is [status-completed] red?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

Could we have [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) be green instead of red? Red to me sounds like rejected or not accepted.

Comment: This post could really use a [tag:status-completed] tag to indicate that it has been rejected.

Comment: And making [tag:status-bydesign] blue? Won't that make the tag section just a bunch of colors? I doubt that will make it readable.

Comment: From a usability perspective the question is very valid. If you post this on UX.SE instead you will get upvotes!

Comment: Well it would be off topic for there as its a feature request.

Answer (score 9):

All mod only tags across all meta sites are red.

Can't see that changing any time soon ;)

Comment: Why doesn't this question have a correctly-colored [meta-tag:status-declined] on it?

Comment: @Won't - that just wouldn't be green